# Cannot check out code on Codeplex using Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, codeplex

I'm a new user to SVN.

I've installed Tortoise SVN using default settings and tried to check out the latest code from Codeplex for the HttpAgilityPack project. I tried this numerous times but the UI would hang for around 5 minutes and then a window popped up box which looks like the following appeared:

[image: sa]

I tried to check out source code for different projects and the result was similar. Also when I tried to access the code repository through my browser, it took a few minutes to load the page (so very slow).

Is there anything I can do to successfully check out and run other SVN commands for source code from Codeplex? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the subversion bridge on codeplex seams to have issues. Updating also fails for some time. codeplex seams to be dead, also MS migrates their project to github.

Comment: codeplex said, they are aware of it: https://twitter.com/codeplex/status/677368914360279040

Comment: today I was able to updates WC from codeplex projects. So try it again

Comment: Codeplex is **still** broken which is why everyone is abandoning it. Even Github can't import from it https://import.github.com/new/source - try pasting a codeplex URL like https://efbulkinsert.svn.codeplex.com/svn and watch it tell you "Imports from Codeplex's SVN bridge are not supported, because Codeplex does not support svnrdump. Please try importing from Codeplex+TFS, or maybe use svn2git."

I usually just download the latest code a zip and go from there. Crappy alternative but it's a crappy situation.